# Return app user id from Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to retrieve the user ids of my friends from Facebook API. However, I am trying to get the app user id, not their facebook user id. Currently I have this

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
            FB.api(
              '/me/friends',
              'GET',
              {"fields":"id,name,email,picture"},
              function(response) {
                  // Insert your code here
                    console.log(response);
                    var data = response.data; //this data is being modified in FollowController
                    var source   = $('#facebook-friends-template').html();
                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                    var html    = template( data );
                    $("#facebook-friends").html(html);
              }
            );              
          }
          else {
           FB.login(function(response) {
              // handle the response
            }, {    
                scope: 'user_friends', 
                return_scopes: true});
          }
        });
```

But I don't know what parameter to pass in for my friend's app user id to return. Do I need to do a batch request to my app's API?

Comment: No /me/friends is correct. But you will only get friends that has granted user_friends permission to the app. Not all users

Comment: @WizKid Yes it works. However, my app is called, let's say exampleApp, and in exampleApp, user's have an id. How do get that id with what i have above?

Comment: /me/friends return friends. Is the data in response.data?

Comment: Object {data: Array[2], paging: Object, summary: Object}
data
:
Array[2]
0
:
Object
id
:
"57010404"
name
:
"Chris Pennington"
picture
:
Object
data
:
Object
is_silhouette
:
false
url
:
"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/10423758_10100749887416971_1041629955570911621_n.jpg?oh=3a2fa7ca8477306a4807d4b5e5ddd3b1&oe=58252D37"
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array[0]
paging
:
Object
summary
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: I would like to have something along the lines of exampleAppId as a property of the user object @WizKid

Comment: So id is there. Just get it out. data[0].id for the first one so just loop through them

Comment: @WizKid I know id is there. But that is the facebook id. I want to be able and make it so the endpoint returns my app user id, NOT facebook id.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117444/discussion-between-kennyusc-and-wizkid).